# empty session value in different $http requests of Angular and Codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, session

I am creating simple authentication project using angular and codeigniter, I am using yeoman structure for angular. So my structure of projects is:
Project:

```
 -- api\ (folder for codeigniter)
    -- application\
       -- controllers\
          -- Login.php
 -- app\
     -- scripts\
        -- controllers\
           -- login.js  (controller of login)
     -- views\
 -- bower_components\
 -- node_modules\
 ....
```

When user logs in then I have called function of Login.php where I am setting session of php using:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user","123");
```

And this is getting set in session successfully (I have checked by printing $_SESSION value).

Then after that I am running a new function of service in app.run( in app.js) to check if user is logged in or not by using:

```
$http.post($rootScope.httpServices+"login/isloggedIn"); 
// URL = localhost/project/api/index.php/login/isloggedIn
```

isloggedIn() is function in Login.php, where I am checking value of session, but there its value is appearing empty. I am running my project using url: http://localhost:9000/#/login in browser.

Is there something which I am missing to get the value of session or is there something that is destroying the value of session on next ajax request. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this ```$this->session->userdata('user');``` instead of ```$_SESSION["user"]```

Comment: this too is not working. I think the issue is because when we send request using one ajax request, it sets session in that particular url and when we send request again to get value of session, it treats it as different domain or host (not sure), so that is why it do not shows its value.

Comment: No. This is not the case, if your sess_cookie_name is same for application, then you must get session data from application even if it is service call.